# Falcor - deep nested references

Tags: javascript, node.js, netflix, falcor

I'm playing with Falcor to see if the company I work for can have a use for it, so I'm quite a newbie.

I'm using model as data source.

This is my model:

```
var model = new falcor.Model({
  cache:{
    currenciesById: {
      "1": { code: "USD", format: "$" },
      "2": { code: "GBP", format: "£" },
      "3": { code: "EUR", format: "€" },
      "4": { code: "YEN", format: "¥"}
    },
    validCurrencies: {
       "1": { $type: "ref", value: ["currenciesById", 1] },
       "2": { $type: "ref", value: ["currenciesById", 2] },
       "3": { $type: "ref", value: ["currenciesById", 3] },
       "4": { $type: "ref", value: ["currenciesById", 4] }
    },
    quotesByPart: {
      "100" : {price: 1768.34, currency: { $type: "ref", value: ["currencyById", 1] }},
      "200" : {price: 2834.44, currency: { $type: "ref", value: ["currencyById", 2] }},
      "201" : {price: 7803.54, currency: { $type: "ref", value: ["currencyById", 3] }},
      "347" : {price: 389.09, currency: { $type: "ref", value: ["currencyById", 4] }}
    },
    quotes: {
      "1": { $type: "ref", value: ["quotesByPart", 100] },
      "2": { $type: "ref", value: ["quotesByPart", 200] },
      "307": { $type: "ref", value: ["quotesByPart", 347] }
    },
    reservedQuotes:{
      "1": { $type: "ref", value: ["quotesByPart", 201] }
    }
  }
});
```

When I make this request:

```
get('quotes[307].["price", "currency"]')
```

This is Falcor's response:

```
{
   "json": {
      "quotes": {
         "307": {
            "price": 389.09,
            "currency": [
               "currencyById",
               4
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is what I was expencting. Falcor finds that quotes[307] is actually a reference to quotesByPart[347] and resolves it, in fact it returns the correct price and a reference to the currency.

I then tried to have Falcor resolve the second reference - currency in the same request.
I tried to write the requests like this:

```
get('quotes[307].["currency"].["code"]')
```

or, out of desperation

```
get('quotes[307].["currency.code"]')
```

and I couldn't get Falcor to resolve the second reference.

Can someone tell me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my model.

The correct model was this one below:

```
var model = new falcor.Model({
  cache:{
    currencyById: {
      "1": { code: "USD", format: "$" },
      "2": { code: "GBP", format: "£" },
      "3": { code: "EUR", format: "€" },
      "4": { code: "YEN", format: "¥"}
    },
    validCurrencies: {
        "1": { $type: "ref", value: ["currencyById", 1] },
        "2": { $type: "ref", value: ["currencyById", 2] },
        "3": { $type: "ref", value: ["currencyById", 3] },
        "4": { $type: "ref", value: ["currencyById", 4] }
    },
    quotesByPart: {
      "100" : {price: 1768.34, currency: { $type: "ref", value: ["currencyById", 1] }},
      "200" : {price: 2834.44, currency: { $type: "ref", value: ["currencyById", 2] }},
      "201" : {price: 7803.54, currency: { $type: "ref", value: ["currencyById", 3] }},
      "347" : {price: 389.09, currency: { $type: "ref", value: ["currencyById", 4] }}
    },
    quotes: {
      "1": { $type: "ref", value: ["quotesByPart", 100] },
      "2": { $type: "ref", value: ["quotesByPart", 200] },
      "307": { $type: "ref", value: ["quotesByPart", 347] }
    },
    reservedQuotes:{
      "1": { $type: "ref", value: ["quotesByPart", 201] }
    }
  }
});
```

with this model Falcor works as expected and even deep nested references are resolved.

Comment: The issue was `currenciesById` should of been `currencyById`? Ok, what would the syntax be for getting `price` of quote and also  `code` and `format` of `currency`?  Is it `get('quotes[307].["price", "currency.code","currency.format"]')`? Docs for Falcor Paths are still lacking...